# How to set a value from a string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I got a command/program that returns a text in standard output as a string, which is "YES" or "NO", how can I set a variable to this string to use it elsewhere?

I want it to behave like

```
Echo Yes << this is from the command, I can't change it
Yes << How it is shown in the CMD window
IF "Yes" is defined goto yes
IF "No" is defined goto no
:yes
echo yes & exit
:no
echo no & exit
```

Comment: You could either use a `for /f` loop, to save the result of your command as a variable, then check that variable with an `if` command; or you could pipe the result of the command to `find` and check for the case insensitive string `Yes` or `No`. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and then read the information. You can then repeat that with both `if /?` and `find /?`. Then choose which you'd prefer, write some code, test it, and if it fails to work as written and intended, you should have sufficient information to edit your question to become on topic.

Comment: I got it, thank you both **Ben Personick** & **Compo**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the output of a command/program, you need to use a `For /F` Loop to parse and take action on the output you are looking to capture.

If you ONLY need to make a choice, using `FIND` or `FINDStr` to make a decision can often be a simpler solution.

So if you want to simply make a choice, and the only output is yes or no, and those are the only two options the output might take you could easily just check for one and assume the other if the 1st condition isn't found:

```cmd
ECHO Yes | FIND /I "Yes" && (
  GOTO :yes
) || (
  GOTO :NO
)
```

If you only want to choose and you're calling a label with the same characters as the output and only such outputs will be produced you could make a select statement with a for-loop which is very nice:

```cmd
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
  ECHO.Yes
') DO (
  GOTO :%%_
)
```

If you might have output that is not a valid choice there are some ways to make the above work by searching the script to validate the output and choose a default option if the label isn't found:

```cmd
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
  ECHO.Yes
') DO (
  TYPE "%~f0" | FIND /I ":%%_" && (
    GOTO :%%_
  ) || (
    GOTO :Default
  )
)

:Default
  Echo. Invalid Result
GOTO :EOF
```

If you want to capture the info and make a choice so you can use the info in another part of the program too, and you again need a `FOR /F` Loop:

```cmd
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
  ECHO.Yes
') DO (
  SET "_Response=%%_"
  GOTO :%%_
)

:Yes
 ECHO.The result was "%_Response%"!
GOTO :EOF
```